# Wordpress - Setting a default 'featured image' for each Catergory

Tags: wordpress

I want to set a default 'Featured Image' for every category that I have.

In my functions.php file I have the following code:-

```
/* ---------------FEATURED POST IMAGE------------------------*/
function default_category_featured_image() {
global $post;
$featured_image_exists = has_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
if (!$featured_image_exists) {
$attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );

if ($attached_image) {
foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment);
}}
else if ( in_category('2') ) {
set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '112');
}
else if ( in_category('3') ) {
set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '115');
}
else if ( in_category('4') ) {
set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '113');
}
else if ( in_category('8') ) {
set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '114');
}
else {
set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '0');
}
}
}
add_action('the_post', 'default_category_featured_image');
```

Which is working for most of the Categories apart from Wordpress. There are 6 posts at the minute that have 'Wordpress' as the category and they all are using category ID '3', but for some unknown reason, a few of the posts that have 'Wordpress' as the category have the default featured image set, where as a few don't have any default image set?

Any idea why this is happening:-

You can see the problem here:-

http://www.web-tricks.co.uk

From the homepage you can see the title 'How to increase WordPress Memory Limit' is working, and 'Web-Tricks Top 10 Best Plugins for WordPress' is now, but they have the same category ID - Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new template for each category, and do a WP_Query that assigns the category.

Then within the loop, you can say if have featured image, show, otherwise show my image.

If that makes sense. If not, i'll try post an example soon. I'm on the fly atm :P